# smooth line in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, plot, graph, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart (v3.0.2) for real-time plotting my data in my android app.
I need to smooth the chart's line (the noise from the sensors).
I understand that I need to use any of the following methods:

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(boolean enabled); 

lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

lineDataSet.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
```

but those methods don't exist when I try to access them on my **ILineDataSet** object.
Any suggestion for how can I smooth my chart's line?

Answer (score 0):

Buddy for real time plotting every time when you add new value to your dataset you need to call:

```
lineDataSet.setDrawCubic(true);
lineDataSet.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will solve your issue whenever you add another value to dataset add above two lines. Also add following lines to your chartview:

```
lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
lineChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned I'm using "ILineDataSet" and not "LineDataSet", and setDrawCubic doesn't exist for that kind of object...